# Finding the Current Active Window in Mac OS X using Python

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there a way to find the application name of the current active window at a given time on Mac OS X using Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Obtain Active window using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10266281/obtain-active-window-using-python)

Comment: I was able to get this working on OSX in Python3 with `pygetwindow`, e.g. `import pygetwindow as gw; gw.getActiveWindow()` - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/77406474/2418744 for a bit more info

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

from AppKit import NSWorkspace
activeAppName = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().activeApplication()['NSApplicationName']
print activeAppName
```

Only works on Leopard, or on Tiger if you have PyObjC installed and happen to point at the right python binary in line one (not the case if you've installed universal MacPython, which you'd probably want to do on Tiger). But Peter's answer with the Carbon way of doing this will probably be quite a bit faster, since importing anything from AppKit in Python takes a while, or more accurately, importing something from AppKit for the first time in a Python process takes a while.

If you need this inside a PyObjC app, what I describe will work great and fast, since you only experience the lag of importing AppKit once.  If you need this to work as a command-line tool, you'll notice the performance hit.  If that's relevant to you, you're probably better off building a 10 line Foundation command line tool in Xcode using Peter's code as a starting point.

Answer (score 21):

The method in the accepted answer was deprecated in OS X 10.7+. The current recommended version would be the following:

```
from AppKit import NSWorkspace
active_app_name = NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace().frontmostApplication().localizedName()
print(active_app_name)
```

Comment: This really helps! How can we get the active window title?

Comment: I know it's possible to do it using AppleScript (calling it through osascript in Python), but up to my knowledge, there's no straightforward way to do it in Python. Here's a link to check the information you can retrieve using Cocoa: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/frontmostApplication

Comment: Originally we used AppleScript to get the current window title, which worked perfectly. But it didn't work if we signed the app. And then I found a native API in Quartz to do it, and that resolved our problem.

Comment: For some reason this always gave me the name of my terminal. The accepted answer got it right. I'm running OS X 10.10.

Comment: @JakeW - could you share how you did it?  what's the api?

Comment: @Yehosef I've added a new answer so that it can display the sample code in a better format. I hope it would be helpful to you.

Comment: @JakeW - thanks!  But where's the answer? I don't see it.

Comment: @Yehosef As suggested by reviewers, I added the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28815863/how-to-get-active-window-title-using-python-in-mac-os/37368813#37368813, which is more relevant. Basically the way to get app name is the same, the native part I found is for getting window title using Quartz.

Answer (score 7):

First off, do you want the window or the application name? This isn't Windows—an application process on Mac OS X can have multiple windows. (Furthermore, this has also been true of Windows for a few years now, although I have no idea what the API looks like for that.)

Second, Carbon or Cocoa?

To get the active window in Cocoa:

```
window = NSApp.mainWindow()
```

To get the name of your process in Cocoa:

```
appName = NSProcessInfo.processInfo().processName()
```

**Edit:** Oh, I think I know what you want. The name of the frontmost process, right?

I don't think there's a way to do it in Cocoa, but here's how to do it in Carbon in C:

```
ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0L, 0L };
OSStatus err = GetFrontProcess(&psn);
/*error check*/

CFStringRef processName = NULL;
err = CopyProcessName(&psn, &processName);
/*error check*/
```

Remember to `CFRelease(processName)` when you're done with it.

I'm not sure what that will look like in Python, or if it's even possible. Python doesn't have pointers, which makes that tricky.

I know PyObjC would translate the latter argument to `CopyProcessName` into `err, processName = CopyProcessName(…)`, but the Carbon bindings don't rely on PyObjC (they're part of core Python 2), and I'm not sure what you do about the PSN either way.

Comment: What do we need to import to get NSApp and NSProcessInto?

Comment: @GreenAsJade: Going by Dirk's answer, presumably Foundation and AppKit.

Comment: Since the original question was about Python, note that `CFRelease` is not necessary with PyObjC.  PyObjC handles calling that for you, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the current frontmost application in a Python script that arranges the windows nicely on my screen (see [`move_window`](https://github.com/SirVer/move_window)).

Of course, the complete credit goes to Peter! But here is the complete program:

```
#include <Carbon/Carbon.h>

int main(int, char) {
    ProcessSerialNumber psn = { 0L, 0L };
    OSStatus err = GetFrontProcess(&psn);

    CFStringRef processName = NULL;
    err = CopyProcessName(&psn, &processName);
    printf("%s\n", CFStringGetCStringPtr(processName, NULL));
    CFRelease(processName);
}
```

Build with `gcc -framework Carbon filename.c`

Comment: How is this an answer for python?

Comment: Also not for Python, but for the new Yosemite JavaScript automation you can use `$.NSWorkspace.sharedWorkspace.activeApplication.objectForKey('NSApplicationName').UTF8String;`. You need to import this first though: `ObjC.import('AppKit')`.

Comment: As of now, 'CopyProcessName' has been explicitly marked deprecated.