# Find out what application (window) is in focus in Java

Tags: java, windows

I'd like to know how I can code a Java program that knows which Windows application is in focus. I can have many windows open but I want to know the one that's being used (like Google Chrome right now as I'm typing this).

I don't need to change anything in the window or application, just need to know its name.

Comment: What do you want do with this window? Probably you can find it only with JNI.

Comment: Would be great to have an answer showing how to do this for all 3 major platforms, i.e windows, mac, and linux, if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm afraid there's no java api for that. JVM does not know anything about the windows it does not manage. You'll probably have to use JNI and call this function

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
```

[MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505%28VS.85%29.aspx)

PS. THere is a `GetWindowText` function that you might want to use if you need to grab the title of the window.

[This post](http://codequirks.blogspot.com/2008/06/user32dll-functions-in-jni.html) has JNI examples that might be helpful for you.

Comment: DllImport?  Looks like C Sharp.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels There are libraries which enable you to bind DLLs in java too. Though this syntax probably is C#.

Comment: Ya the syntax is from c#. I just meant to show the dll and the function signature.

Comment: This seems like a nice alternative! I had never heard of JNI before, seems a bit confusing. Could I ask you to specify what I'd have to import/call to make this work in a java class? It'd be even better if you could just write a simple class that implements the GetWindowText function. Thnx!

Comment: @Daniel Check out the examples in that post.

Comment: For my 2 cents, I think you're much better off using JNA rather than JNI.  It's based on JNI, but it's a lot simpler to use (I think).

Answer (score 35):

As the others have already pointer out, there is no portable way to get this on all platforms. But to make things worse: There not even a consistent way on MS Windows. I will provide some code that will solve the problem for different platforms and will point out the limitations. Use at your own risk, the code may provide wrong results or not run at all because of security reasons. If it runs on your machine, it will not mean that it will run equally well on other machines.

The code uses JNA. During my experiments I had problems with different versions of JNA and the JNA platform library. It might be best to compile it yourself, so you have a consistent environment.

### Windows

The answer provided by kichik was correct at its time but will not work with Windows 8 in all cases. The problem is, that it will not handle Metro apps correctly. Unfortunately there is currently no stable API to get the name of the currently running Metro app. I have inserted some hints in the code, but it's best to wait until Microsoft will provide you with an API.

On Windows you will also have problems with privileged apps and with the UAC dialog. So you will not always get a correct answer.

```
public interface Psapi extends StdCallLibrary {
    Psapi INSTANCE = (Psapi) Native.loadLibrary("Psapi", Psapi.class);

    WinDef.DWORD GetModuleBaseNameW(Pointer hProcess, Pointer hModule, byte[] lpBaseName, int nSize);
}
    if (Platform.isWindows()) {
        final int PROCESS_VM_READ=0x0010;
        final int PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION=0x0400;
        final User32 user32 = User32.INSTANCE;
        final Kernel32 kernel32=Kernel32.INSTANCE;
        final Psapi psapi = Psapi.INSTANCE;
        WinDef.HWND windowHandle=user32.GetForegroundWindow();
        IntByReference pid= new IntByReference();
        user32.GetWindowThreadProcessId(windowHandle, pid);
        WinNT.HANDLE processHandle=kernel32.OpenProcess(PROCESS_VM_READ | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, true, pid.getValue());

        byte[] filename = new byte[512];
        Psapi.INSTANCE.GetModuleBaseNameW(processHandle.getPointer(), Pointer.NULL, filename, filename.length);
        String name=new String(filename);
        System.out.println(name);
        if (name.endsWith("wwahost.exe")) { // Metro App
            // There is no stable API to get the current Metro app
            // But you can guestimate the name form the current directory of the process
            // To query this, see:
            // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16110936/read-other-process-current-directory-in-c-sharp
        }
```

### Linux / Unix / X11

With X11 we have three problems:

1. Because of network transparency, multiple windows from completely different machines might be mixed in the same X11. So neither name nor PID of the process belonging to a window might be make sense on the machine you are querying.
2. Most windows managers have mutliple desktops. On each desktop there can be a different application in the foreground
3. Tiling window managers (like [XMonad](http://xmonad.org/)) don't have the concept of a foreground window. They arrange all windows in a way, so each window is in the foreground at the same time.

On X11 it makes more sense to query for the window that currently has the focus.

```
public interface XLib extends StdCallLibrary {
    XLib INSTANCE = (XLib) Native.loadLibrary("XLib", Psapi.class);

    int XGetInputFocus(X11.Display display, X11.Window focus_return, Pointer revert_to_return);
}

if(Platform.isLinux()) {  // Possibly most of the Unix systems will work here too, e.g. FreeBSD
        final X11 x11 = X11.INSTANCE;
        final XLib xlib= XLib.INSTANCE;
        X11.Display display = x11.XOpenDisplay(null);
        X11.Window window=new X11.Window();
        xlib.XGetInputFocus(display, window,Pointer.NULL);
        X11.XTextProperty name=new X11.XTextProperty();
        x11.XGetWMName(display, window, name);
        System.out.println(name.toString());
    }
```

### Mac OS X

Mac OS X does not focus on windows but on applications. So it makes sense to ask for the currently active application. Older versions of Mac OS X provide multiple desktops. Newer versions can have multiple fullscreen applications open at the same time. So you might not always get a correct answer.

```
    if(Platform.isMac()) {
        final String script="tell application \"System Events\"\n" +
                "\tname of application processes whose frontmost is tru\n" +
                "end";
        ScriptEngine appleScript=new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("AppleScript");
        String result=(String)appleScript.eval(script);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
```

### Conclusion

When I played around with this code, it worked in the most basic cases. But if you want this code to run reliable, you will have to put in a lot of polish. Decide for yourself if it is worth it.

To make the code complete, here is the import section I used:

```
    import com.sun.jna.Native;
    import com.sun.jna.Platform;
    import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.unix.X11;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinNT;
    import com.sun.jna.ptr.IntByReference;
    import com.sun.jna.win32.StdCallLibrary;

    import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
    import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
    import javax.script.ScriptException;
```

Of course you will have to rearrange the parts of the code. I used one big class with the interfaces at the beginning a and then the rest in one big main method.

Comment: Hi Stefan, in the Linux/Unix code sample you're loading the XLib with "Psapi.class".
I do not get why you're loading with "Psapi.class" and not with the the own "XLib.class" interface. Can you explain it?

Answer (score 7):

As Hovercraft Full Of Eels said, [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) is your best bet here. Unlike JNI, you won't have to compile any C code for it.

To get the process name:

1. Call [GetForegroundWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the window handle
2. Call [GetWindowThreadProcessId()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633522%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to figure out which process owns it
3. Call [OpenProcess()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get a handle to the process (with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ`)
4. Call [GetModuleFileNameEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683198%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to get the process name from the handle. You can also call [GetModuleBaseName()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683196%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for just the module name without the full path.

A full example is available in [Getting active window information in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6393901/492773).

C code can be found [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14843/Finding-module-name-from-the-window-handle).

Comment: Well, the original question was for Windows, but the same method should apply for anything else. For Mac OS X, you can try porting this [Python code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373020/finding-the-current-active-window-in-mac-os-x-using-python).  It should get you started on which functions to call.

Comment: The bounty is so hopefully linux / mac answer could be found .Thanks for your help so far though. :)

Comment: @ClickUpvote there are other answers on this site that will tell you how to accomplish it on Mac and Linux in python; you just need to port the code to java

Comment: Incredible, very helpful.