# Using JNA to get GetForegroundWindow();

Tags: java, windows, winapi, jna

I asked a similar question on a previous thread ([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206633/java-find-out-what-application-window-is-in-focus)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206633/java-find-out-what-application-window-is-in-focus) but I was guided to use JNI, and I'm not having much success with it... I've read some tutorials and while some work fine, others don't I still can't get the information I need, which is the title of the window on the foreground.

Now I'm looking into JNA but I can't figure out how to access GetForegroundWindow() ... I think I can print the text once I get the handle to the window using this code (found on another thread):

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class jnatest {
    public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
        User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);

        int GetWindowTextA(PointerType hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
    }

    public static void main(){
        byte[] windowText = new byte[512];

        PointerType hwnd = //GetForegroundWindow() (?)...
        User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 512);
        System.out.println(Native.toString(windowText));

    }
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

How about simply adding a method call to match the native GetForegroundWindow to your interface, something like so:

```
import com.sun.jna.*;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.win32.*;

public class JnaTest {
   public interface User32 extends StdCallLibrary {
      User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32", User32.class);
      HWND GetForegroundWindow();  // add this
      int GetWindowTextA(PointerType hWnd, byte[] lpString, int nMaxCount);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
      byte[] windowText = new byte[512];

      PointerType hwnd = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow(); // then you can call it!
      User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextA(hwnd, windowText, 512);
      System.out.println(Native.toString(windowText));
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! I can't compile that code, for some reason, I can't import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND; and HWND GetForegroundWindow(); seems to be invalid. Naturally, I get an error trying to call it also. Could I be missing something?

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels No, I submitted the reply too quickly by accident. Now it's the full reply :P

Comment: Any help would be appreciated:)

Comment: @Daniel: This may be a silly stupid question of mine, but have you downloaded the JNA libraries?  Have you added them to your classpath, or if using an IDE to your IDE's build path?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Eclipse and i've included the jna.jar in the build path. It only complains about loading import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND; the others load fine. Not at all :P, I admit to having done sillier things!

Comment: @Daniel, do you include both jna.jar and platform.jar in your build path's libraries?

Comment: Oh... I didn't realise that the JNA library was more than jna.jar ... Fixed it now! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Daniel: glad to help!  Yeah it's somewhere in the documentation, but it's been a while since I've read it, so I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 6):

If getting the window title is all you want to do, you don't have to explicitly
load the `user32` library. JNA comes with it, in the `platform.jar` file (at
least in v3.4 it does).

I got this working here:

```
import com.sun.jna.Native;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HWND;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;

public class JnaApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("title is " + getActiveWindowTitle());
    }

    private static String getActiveWindowTitle() {
        HWND fgWindow = User32.INSTANCE.GetForegroundWindow();
        int titleLength = User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowTextLength(fgWindow) + 1;
        char[] title = new char[titleLength];
        User32.INSTANCE.GetWindowText(fgWindow, title, titleLength);
        return Native.toString(title);
    }

}
```

See more on [User32's Javadoc](http://twall.github.com/jna/3.4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/platform/win32/User32.html). Its got almost all the functions in the user32 library.