# Detecting Graphical interface after calling Runtime.exec()

Tags: java, runtime

I'm trying to integrate with a legacy system. The legacy system uses dialog windows to report errors. It have no return codes at all except for the dialog   windows. I start the legacy system with `Runtime.exec()`.

Is there a way to detect if the executed program has spawned dialog windows or any other graphical interface? This solution is done in Windows and the executed program is an exe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution i did, is to use the snippet code that @Gerrett Hall linked to. That snippet code check the active window before i run the command and save the name.

Then after a vile if the command have not returned check if the active window have changed. if it have, kill the process(Alt. send a return key global).

To get the info from the dialog i could use Ctrl + C to copy the content of the dialog and reading the paste buffer to copy the message in to the log. Have not figured out that part yet.

And yes this is a ugly hack but so is the legacy system to.

Answer (score 1):

If the legacy system report errors in console, is possible get your erros.
Simply take the inputstream of error and do your reading.

Like this:

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);
// any error message?
InputStream error = proc.getErrorStream(); 
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(error);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String line=null;
while ( (line = br.readLine()) != null)
      System.out.println(" ERROR >" + line);
```

I recommend to read: [Runtime.exec() quirks](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=4)

Hope this help.

Comment: I afraid that does not work. As i sad it only interacts with graphical windows. There is nothing on stderr.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this [JNA snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java/6393901#6393901) to poll for windows started by your process.

AFAIK, you can only get the standard and error output streams from a process using the Java Process API.