# Getting information about new window opened

Tags: java, windows, java-native-interface

[Getting active window information in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java) allows me to check what an active window is.

What I need is to run thread in background and check if any new window appeared. How can this be done?

I need a method to get my thread notified that a new window appeared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to poll the windows and check if any changed.  I don't know of any way to get notified about new windows but you can get notified about new processes.  Try one of [these](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) [two](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559951%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API calls.