# How to get title of cuurently active window(parent and child) in java

Tags: java, passwords, window

I am developing a passPro application in this i want to need a title of currently active window like Adobe reader, Ms word,excel,access etc.
The all the application having password protection when i have clicked on a particular application the "Enter the password" like child window gets opened. I want to that child window title.
I am developing appliaction that automatically detects passwords from my access db when i opened any password protected file application(like access,word,pdf or PPT).

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java/6393901#6393901