# How to know the drop object in DropTargetDragEvent Java Swing comes from Outlook

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, outlook

In a drop event (DropTargetDropEvent) in Java Swing which files,emails and others can be drop into a drop target, I would like to know if the drop object is an email from outlook. In the code below both file and email can enter the "if" condition.

```
public void drop(java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent dropEvt )
{   
    Transferable transferable = dropEvt.getTransferable();
    if(transferable.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor))
    {
        //Dropped files or email from Outlook enters this condition
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think it's possible to know exactly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the post below which answers my question, need to get the active window information on the dragEnter event method.

[Getting active window information in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java)