# How to know the current program the user is using?

Tags: java

I am creating a time tracker that keep track of time the user spend on a specific program, And I want help the user control what programs should my time tracker operate on, Is there a way to know the current window or program the user is using in java ?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391439/getting-active-window-information-in-java