# Highlighting the same explorer windows on explorer /select command

Tags: java, windows

We use explorer /select command with the file path to open the file in windows explorer. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/152457 But on multiple invocations it opens a new window everytime. I am invoking the command from a java application using the process runtime APIs.

is it possible to have one window being opened ?. For e.g. if an explorer with c:/A is being opened ,repeated invocation of the same command must open the same window which is opened. ?

cheers

Saurav

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that your problem does not have a simple solution. 
According to my understanding the "window sharing" of expplorer is not the  explorer's feature. Please take a look on the following article: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/241911

(Although this article is talking about Internet Explorer I guess it is relevant for file exploerer as well).

According to my user  experience the window sharing happens only when you are getting to directory via some kind of shortcut and does not happen when you are running explorer explicitly. For example if you type in "run" window "explorer" the new window is always created, however if you type "c:\" the window will be re-used.

You want  to execute explorer with specific option, so you have to run it explicitly, therefore no window re-use can be achieved.

But I can suggest you 2 workarounds.

- Do not use `/select` option. "Run" the base directory of the file you want to select. This  will guarantee the window reuse. Then "select" file using `java.awt.Robot` by "typing" its name.
- Manage the opened Explorer windows yourself into your java application. You can store map of file-to-exploerer window handler. When application wants to run open explorer for file that  is already selected in other explorer window, activate it. To do this you need some JNI/JNA code. Take a look on the following discussions for details.

[In Java Swing how do you get a Win32 window handle (hwnd) reference to a window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/386792/in-java-swing-how-do-you-get-a-win32-window-handle-hwnd-reference-to-a-window)

[Find out what application (window) is in focus in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5206633/find-out-what-application-window-is-in-focus-in-java)

Comment: thanks a lot Alex for detailed answer...this helps..i will check the links