# python script or applescript to get active pdf in foreground window, open in another application

Tags: python, macos, pdf, applescript, foreground

I'm interested in writing an OS X service and figured python would be the easiest way. Is it possible to write a script to get the active PDF in the foreground window of any app, and then open that file (or a copy) in a different app?

What function calls would I need to get this done? Would it be easier to do this with AppleScript?

Edit: Apparently, the application I want to send the PDF to (Papers 2) isn't AppleScriptable. Python it is, I guess.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373020/finding-the-current-active-window-in-mac-os-x-using-python

Comment: Thanks. This is the first time I've looked at the AppKit functions, so it's a little overwhelming, but I'm going to keep digging.